# What is the user asked to do when updating an app with *added* permissions?

Tags: android, permissions

I have an app in the Play store, but I want to add a user permission to the next release. Does the phone throw up the app permission screen for the added permissions?

Usually, the app permissions don't change and it is autoupdated or manually updated in a single step. But what happens when you add permissions? I've tried to Google it but can't find an answer.

(I realize this is not a code question, but it surely must be an important one for Android developers faced with this problem).

Comment: I've been through that. It shows the permission screen for all the permissions needed, both old and new. I'm also fairly sure it's documented somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the phone throw up the app permission screen for the added permissions?

Yes. However, it shows all permissions, with the new ones highlighted with the word "New".